# Change site content based on a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to Change my site content once a week at midnight, how can I schedule that with javascript/jquery?

Comment: you need to be WAAY more specific.

Comment: you need the jQueryCron plugin

Comment: You may need to give more details to get a positive answer, but thing for sure, that you'd need a scheduling service such as cron or Windows Schedule tasks

Comment: Want to feature articles about the week in history (just some regular text) & I'm looking for an easier way to do that then actually uploading it at Sunday midnight...

Answer (score 1):

You can't with just client-side scripting. You should look into [cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html). It'll let you run a script that does whatever you need to do to update your content at set intervals.

Comment: ...no, if he doesn't care about crawler he can show/hide div basing on client time without using any server site scripting or cron